# MySQL - Creating an associative table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key, polymorphic-associations, cascade

I have the following table structures:

Cases:

```
(PK)
case_id | case_notes | time
1       | blah       | timestamp
2       | blah       | timestamp
3       | blah       | timestamp
.       | .          | .
```

There will be an "infinite" amount of cases so each has it's own unique ID.

I now have a "tags" table.  There can be an "infinite" amount of tags so each tag has it's own unique ID:

```
(PK)
tag_id | tag
1      | tag-1
2      | tag-2
3      | tag-3
.      | .
```

Now I would like each case to be associated with n'-many tags.  Due to this I need an "association" table (is that the right word?) to link cases to tags.

```
(PK??? not sure)    (FK)      (FK)
id | case_id | tag_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 2
4  | 3       | 1
5  | 3       | 2
6  | 3       | 3
.  | .       | .
```

In the above example case 1 is associated with tag-1 and tag-2, case 2 is associated with just tag-2, and case 3 is associated with tags 1,2, and 3.

I want to be able to do the following SELECTS:

```
SELECT all cases (including their notes) which are associated with tag-1
SELECT all tags associated with a particular case.
```

On a high level you can imagine the system as the following giant table:

```
case_id | case_notes | time      | tags
1       | blah       | timestamp | (tag-1, tag-2)
2       | blah       | timestamp | (tag-2)
3       | blah       | timestamp | (tag-1, tag-2, tag-3)
.       | .          | .         |
```

Comment: Have you looked at how to [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) tables tied together by [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)?

Comment: Yes, "association table" is a phrase commonly used to describe this circumstance.  I would omit the surrogate `id` from the association table and have `case_id`, `tag_id` together as the compound primary key.

Answer (score 4):

For that many-to-many 'relation' table, don't bother to have an `id`.  Simply have

```
PRIMARY KEY(case_id, tag_id),
INDEX(tag_id, case_id)
```

Note that one of those works perfectly for one of your `SELECT`s, the other works perfectly for the other.  (Use `ENGINE=InnoDB`.)

To get `(tag-1, tag-2, tag-3)`, use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

`FOREIGN KEY`s are optional; I would not bother.

Comment: Why do I need a primary key and an index?  Doesn't a primary key imply an index?

Comment: Yes, a PRIMARY KEY is an index.  In a compound index (multiple columns) the order is vital.  Think about searching a list of names when you have a first name, but the list is sorted by last name.  `(case_id, tag_id)` is used for "ind all the tags for a given case".  `(tag_id, case_id)` is for "find all the cases with a given tag".  So, they are different, and you need both.

Comment: Nice analogy about the phone directory sorted by last name but you want to search by first name - good example for future reference. +1

Comment: You may like my [blog on compound indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and [index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  The latter has a section devoted to 'Many-to-Many Mapping table'.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is frequently called a "joining table" - a many to many connection. Athough the word "associative" is readily understandable in the context, I would use the term "joining" table.

You can put either a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY on the fields   (case_id, tag_id) - no need for a PRIMARY KEY with id - it's superfluous.